# how to fix redux time issue with react date picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, redux, react-datepicker

i am using the react datepicker module and in that i am using it only for month and year picker. when i get the date in my onChange in react date picker. i get 'Mon Nov 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)' and in my redux store i get `2021-10-31T20:00:00.000Z`. there is a four hours lap due to which i get the error `date.format is not a function` and in some cases i get invalid time format error as well. so please if anybody knows let me know.
my code for date picker is below

```
<DatePicker
  selected={passenger?.passportExp}
  onChange={(date) => {
    modifyPassenger(index, { passportExp: date });
  }}
  maxDate={newDate(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 1, 0)}
  showMonthYearPicker
  dateFormat="MMM yyyy"
  onFocusChange={({ focused }) => this.setState({ passportExp: focused })}
/>;
```

Comment: the current date is shown when i choose the month november

Comment: First, the date displayed is correct. `Mon Nov 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0400`  is the same as `2021-10-31T20:00:00.000Z` (`Z` denote as GMT+0). As for the `date.format` error, you sure the `onChange` function returns a `Date` object instead of a string?

Comment: onChange returns this... Mon Nov 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)

Comment: onChange does not return an object in datepicker

Comment: Is that a `string` or a `Date`? I suspect you load the date from Redux back to the picker at some point. If the date you get from `onChange` is in fact a `string`, then clearly there is no such thing call `string.format("MMM yyyy")`.

Comment: @MatthewKwong. ohhh so i would need to convert this date to an object?